# Handling Inbox.items collection - VSTO Outlook Visual Basic

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, outlook

I couldn't find anything regarding a search by conversation ID in the Outlook.Items object collection (corresponding an outlook inbox)

**Scenario**:
we designed a website that requests an email to be searched in outlook client through a table insert

```
insert into Request(UserID,CID,emailDate,outlookAccount)
values ('myUserID','28603734D8EE4316A59257895B1B4A1A','2020-02-11','myOutlookAccount@outlook.com')
```

From out VSTO add-in (visual basic) we are recurrently polling for an eventual request on the mentioned table (Request), once there is a request that belongs to the user, we trigger below's function

```
Private Sub SearchEmail(myConversationID As String, emailDate As String, outlookAccount As String)

        For Each account As Outlook.Account In myOutlookInstance.GetNamespace("MAPI").Accounts
            'i lower de displayname in order to match database information
            If (account.DisplayName.ToLower() = outlookAccount) Then
                Dim mailCollection As Outlook.Items = account.DeliveryStore.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox).Items
                Dim filter As String = "[ConversationID] =" + "'" + myConversationID + "'"
                Dim matchedMail As Outlook.MailItem = mailCollection.Find(filter)
                matchedMail.Display()
                matchedMail.Save()
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

However I can't make it work. I'm not quite sure but it might be a possibility that filtering by "ConversationID" field won't work. For that reason, I tried with this alternative (it doesn't work either)

```
    Private Sub SearchEmail(myConversationID As String, emailDate As String, outlookAccount As String)

        For Each account As Outlook.Account In myOutlookInstance.GetNamespace("MAPI").Accounts
            Dim mailCollection As Outlook.Items = account.DeliveryStore.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox).Items
            Dim eval = False
            For Each item As Object In mailCollection
                If (TypeOf item Is Outlook.MailItem) Then
                    Dim mail As Outlook.MailItem = item
                    Dim myCID As String = mail.ConversationID
                    If (eval = False And (myConversationID = myCID)) Then
                        mail.Display()
                        mail.Save()
                        eval = True
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next

    End Sub
```

Unfortunately (and avoiding the performance and readability issue), this last alternative raises below's issue:

> System.InvalidCastException: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE) at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem.get_ConversationID()

Could any one help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

After, a while trying to figure out what that issue raised is about, i found that it is raised because i reach a non Outlook.Mailitem object and try to call a method that is not supported for that non Outlook.Mailitem (such as display or save)
However, i couldn't get a deffinitive answer regarding a search / filter by conversationID, my definitive guess is that i'm not allowed to. So the best chance i get is to filter as much as i can with the received Date and iterate comparing the Conversation ID property on each item that it hits with the loop

Find below my Work Around:

```
Private Function SearchEmail(myConversationID As String, emailDate As DateTime, outlookAccount As String)

        For Each account As Outlook.Account In myOutlookInstance.GetNamespace("MAPI").Accounts
            If (account.DisplayName.ToLower() = outlookAccount) Then

                Dim mailCollection As Outlook.Items = account.DeliveryStore.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox).Items
                mailCollection.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)
                Dim myRestrictedMailCollection = mailCollection.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= " & "'" & emailDate.ToShortDateString() & "'" & " AND [ReceivedTime] <= " & "'" & emailDate.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString() & "'")
                Dim mail As Outlook.MailItem

                For Each item In myRestrictedMailCollection

                    If (TypeOf item Is Outlook.MailItem) Then

                        mail = item

                        If (myConversationID = mail.ConversationID) Then
                            mail.Display()
                            mail.Save()
                            Return True
                        End If

                    End If

                Next

            End If
        Next

        Return False

    End Function
```